# How to add a break line in a Symbol override?

Tags: sketch-app

I have a symbol with a text override, I would like to add a break-line. But I don't know if this is possible, I tried adding `\n` or hitting `command+enter` without much luck.

Any idea how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 24):

`Option + return` inserts a new line of text, whilst `control + return` inserts a line break.

Answer (score 1):

Use option-return to insert a new line of text.

Comment: You can also use ctrl + return